# Can I create a single VPN in GCP that provides access to multiple projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

Instead of creating a VPN to every GCP project in our organization, can I somehow create a "super" VPN that can access all the projects? I was looking at shared VPC, but I can't figure out from the docs whether shared VPC will solve the problem. I'm not the best at networking and maybe I'm overlooking something. Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 solutions to solve this

- Create a project with the VPN and then create peering with other projects. The problem with this is that you are limited to [25 peering per VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#vpc-peering). In addition, VPC peering has another limitation: transitivity is forbidden. If you have a peering between A and B and between B and C, A can'y reach C, the transitivity isn't permitted and that can cause some issues/limitation later in your design.
- Use Shared VPC. You have a host project with a VPC with your VPN, and then service project that use either their own VPC (for standalone application) or the shared VPC. You have detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#hybrid_cloud_scenario). However in this solution, all the service project have access to the same VPC, and thus all the VM of the services projects can access to the VPC ressources (others VM, VPN, ...). The firewall rules will be very important; and a good way to solve this is to use [firewall rules based on service account](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts).

Comment: Both solves the issue but -in your experience- which is more "recommended"? (imagine a scenario with 10 projects and a single VPN connection in a main project). One issue I see on the first one is the overhead of knowing all the subnets for each project to avoid overlapping ranges

Comment: The  shared VPC is the enterprise grade recommended. All depends on the evolution of your architecture.